# Is it possible to change the gcloud sdk's oauth app?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am using `gcloud auth login` + `container clusters get-credentials` to e.g. fetch credentials for a kubernetes installation. This works great ;).

But whenever gcloud auth login is called a oauth browser is shown, which presents:

[image: google cloud sdk wants to access your google account]

That's ok! I was wondering if it's possible to change the oauth app used in this screen from "google cloud sdk" to a company wide application? E.g. we have a OAuth Enabled Google Project and I would like my co workers to „allow“ this app and not the generic „google cloud sdk“.

PS: I am aware of the fact that there are service accounts for headless login -> but I want the user to authenticate personally

Comment: Could you include an example of what you would like to see?

Comment: Added as: „ E.g. we have a OAuth Enabled Google Project and I would like my co workers to „allow“ this app and not the generic „google cloud sdk“.“

Comment: No, you cannot change this screen. The CLI uses a special identity with Google authentication. Google generates the text displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This screen doesn't belong to "google cloud sdk" app, it's part of OAuth2 flow. Here it's the explicit permissions flow: It ask the user to consent the permissions to the app (name "client" in the OAuth doc).

So, here it's the Google identity provider which present this page. And you can't customize it.

Comment: Yup. I added that I would like to use a different oauth app instead of the official „google cloud sdk“ app when running `gcloud auth login`

Comment: Why to do this?? Do you want to use, at the end, the `gcloud auth print-identity-token` (or access-token) on other app? Like IAP?

Comment: In response to your update, is the impersonate feature enough for you?

Comment: I do this to fetch the credentials for the kubernetes cluster.  Impersonate into the user, while providing a super-admin service token to everybody, would be not a good idea :).I was just wondering if every developer must allow this app or if it is possible to use a custom one for cli work like getting access to the cluster.

Comment: PS: it is totally fine, if it is not possible - I was just wondering of it might be possible :)

Comment: ` Impersonate into the user, while providing a super-admin service token to everybody, would be not a good idea :)` Correct, if you grant these permission at the Project level. But you can grant the impersonnification on service account for only some users. But it's a lot of management. If  you can use the default app, it's better!! And easier/simpler!